# Active Directory Powershell script is giving me a hard time

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I am trying to get my PowerShell script to query active directory, return the computer description and Organizational unit the computer sits in.  I am referencing my .csv for the computer names.  I can get it to run but nothing is being appended to the .csv Any help would be appreciatted

```
# Define the file path
$file_path = "C:\Temp\Description.csv"

# Read the contents of the file
$content = Import-Csv $file_path

# Define the Active Directory query
$filter = "(description -like '*$($content.Description)*')"

# Search for the user in Active Directory
$users = Get-ADUser -Filter $filter -Properties * | Select-Object Name, Description, DistinguishedName

# Update the CSV file with the results
$csv = Import-Csv $file_path
foreach ($row in $csv) {
    foreach ($user in $users) {
        if ($row.Name -eq $user.Name) {
            $row.Description = $user.Description
            $row.DistinguishedName = $user.DistinguishedName
        }
    }
}
$csv | Export-Csv $file_path -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Open the CSV file with notepad.  You are writing to same file you read and may of destroyed the original data.

Comment: Import the csv, process the data, then write back to another csv. Don't try to do it all in one.

Comment: Your question is about getting some info for AD Computers, so why in your code you suddenly switch to `Get-ADUser` and not `Get-ADComputer` ??

Comment: When you say "nothing is being appended", do you mean that the desired _modifications_ of the preexisting rows are not being performed? Please [edit] your question to clarify, also with respect to Theo's question.

Answer (score 0):

You are using for the filter, a property that contains multiple descriptions.
If all descriptions are the same, select the first one, and then filter.

```
$csv = Import-Csv -Path 'C:\Temp\Description.csv'
$description = $csv | Select-Object -First 1 -ExpandProperty Description
# Or
$description = ($csv[0]).Description
$filter = "description -like '*$description*'"
```

Now, if you have multiple descriptions, wrap everything into a foreach loop.
Also, no need to import the CSV multiple times.
It's important to separate things as well, let's put the modified data in another object to export later.

```
[System.Collections.ArrayList]$outputCsv = @()
foreach ($row in (Import-Csv -Path 'C:\Temp\Description.csv')) {

    # Don't use -Properties *. It's an expensive operation.
    # Name and DistinguishedName are standard properties, the only non-standard we need is Description
    $users = Get-ADUser -Filter "description -like '*$description*'" -Properties Description
    
    # Do not modify the original row in a loop. PS throws an error.
    $finalRow = [PSCustomObject]$row
    
    # If you have no repeated users, you don't need another loop.
    $user = $users | Where-Object { $PSItem.Name -eq $finalRow.Name }
    if ($user) {
        $finalRow.Description = $user.Description
        $finalRow.DistinguishedName = $user.DistinguishedName
    }
    [void]$outputCsv.Add($finalRow)
}

# Don't use the same file to avoid errors.
$finalRow | Export-Csv -Path 'C:\Temp\DescriptionUpdated.csv'
```

If you do have repeated users, I suggest removing them from the CSV.
The property 'Description' it's also not a good candidate for filtering.
You can use 'Name', or better yet, 'SamAccountName'. With it you don't need the  filter at all, you can use -Identity instead.

Hope it helps.
Happy scripting!